# USRP N210 Main clock rate and The transmission signal Sampling Rate

Tags: digital, software-defined-radio, usrp

I am testing the transmission and receiving signal using two USRP N210. The communication setting as follows:

```
fc = 2.43e9;        % Hz
bW = 5e6;
fs = 5e6;           % tx_Sampling Rate = rx_Sampling Rate
```

From Time and Frequency Windows in GNURadio,  I think I've received the signal. For the signal I will be processing with, there are some confused questions for me. One is the N210's main clock rate is 100MHz, the setting Sampling rate is 5MHz. Did the USRP N210 "use" each transmission
baseband samples 20 times when processing the baseband signal I emit?]
The example like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Did the USRP N210 "use" each transmission baseband samples 20 times when processing the baseband signal I emit?

No, it *correctly* interpolates the samples twentyfold. (I.e., it uses an appropriate low-pass filter impulse response as interpolation filter, not a sample-and-hold.)

That's done on the FPGA in the N210.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Is there any similarity between the interpolation of this processing step and the DUC of the signal transmission ?

Comment: It's exactly that.

Comment: Hey @zechuanzhang you just removed the upvote here – why? I'd argue I'm not wrong, having done technical work with, and on the N210 itself, as well as paid tech support for roughly a decade.

Comment: Hi Marcus. Sorry for canceling the answer reception by mistake.  I am using MATLAB to simulate the DUC and DDC process of N210. I got some understanding and also encountered some doubts. I revisited the question and thought it might be a bit vague. Maybe I should rephrase the question?